# How do you make a literal T in a PHP date function?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a literal `T` in a PHP `date()` function. I have the following line in my PHP:

> echo date ("F j, Y \a\t g:i A", filemtime($htmlname));

But this, instead of printing out a `T`, it prints out a tab character. I *could* change the `""`s surrounding the date format to `''`, but **that's not what I want.**

In summary, I was wondering if it was possible to make a literal `T` inside of single-quotes.

Comment: Try `"... \a\\t ..."`.

Comment: @DCoder Oh, I probably should have tried that. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to provide a reason.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you mean for why I can't use single quotes?

Comment: Read up on quotes in the PHP manual. Not related to the date function at all: no extra magic here.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date ('F j, Y \a\t g:i A', filemtime($htmlname));
```

Put the date format in single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: I said I didn't want to do that in the OP. Yes, I know that works.

Comment: Duh. Classic case of TL;DR. Sorry about that.